# How can I stop the regex at first match?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which goes like this.

```
010002 D324Y56HY INTEREST 

010002 SAD21 INTEREST
```

I am trying to create two groups here with the regex `(010002)[\s\S]\*INTEREST`

But the regex matches last occurrence of `INTEREST`. I need it to stop the matching at the first occurrence and create another group with the next occurrences. Can someone guide me please?

Please find the link below.

https://regex101.com/r/tXfBGf/1/

Comment: What language programming you are using? Please, add the tag of it in your question.

Comment: @hamedbaziyad It's PHP in regex. I have tagged it thanks!

Comment: If I understand you right, you probably need to make the '*' quantifier ungreedy. In https://regex101.com/r/tXfBGf/1/, this means that you add a "U" (after "gm") in the "set regex options". See field containing the regular expressions: you have flags in the right part.

Comment: Set the ungreedy (`U`) option on your regex.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Thank you so much! I wasn't sure how to make the regex ungreedy. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/(010002)[\s\S]*?INTEREST/
```

(add question mark for shortest match)

Comment: This achieves the same result as `/(010002)[\s\S]*INTEREST/U`